# Why is my SQL query not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I create a profileController which functions to display user data based on the email used when logging in, I use the authentication function provided by Laravel and I create a user table that stores user data, then I want to display the user's data based on the email received when logging in? Any suggestions for improvement? I can't get that user data.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Profil;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class profilController extends Controller
{
    public function profil(){
        $user = Auth::user();
        $students = Profil::all();

        $user_email = $user->email;
        $students_email = $students->email;

        $query = Profil::select('SELECT * FROM $students WHERE $user->email = $students->email');

        return view('menus.profile',['students'=> $query]);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `Profil::where('email',$students->email)->first()` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

you can use [firstWhere](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-first-where) to get first profile while email is equal to the current user's email:

```
 $user_email = $user->email;
 $query = Profil::firstWhere('email', $user_email);
```